# Do wards reveal players hiding in Shadow Pads?

Tags: paragon

If I place a ward while a player is standing in a Shadow Pad, will it reveal them?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging I believe I have found your answer (as well as a lot more good information about Paragon).  As seen here on the [Paragon Reddit Page](https://www.reddit.com/r/paragon/comments/4bwhh1/help_me_understand_wards/) : Traffickin Said:

"You can't see through the jungle. There are walls and aerial cover everywhere, and invis pads. You're only able to just see down the lanes, and the only time enemies can be seen through terrain is when your team/buildings have vision on them." In response to a lot of other good information about Shadow Pads vs Wards.  I hope this helps!